# jQuery tool tip on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in need of a very lightweight tooltip similar to the 1 found here http://www.history.com/videos when you hover a video link under "Popular Videos", a tooltip fades into place, it stays there and you can even select text on it until you move the cursor off it.  Facebook and Google+ also have a similar style tool-tip as well as stackoverflow when you hover over a tag.  Can someone provide a light weight method of doing this.

I have search and looked at many existing "plugins" they are all somewhat bloated though.  Thanks for any help

Comment: how come i am not seeing tooltips in chrome, is it showing up for you in chrome

Comment: Hi, I am using chrome, are you going to almost the bottom of the page under "Popular Videos" heading?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple way you could accomplish this:

```
var timeout;

function hide() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#tooltip").hide('fast');
    }, 500);
};

$("#tip").mouseover(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $("#tooltip").stop().show('fast');
}).mouseout(hide);

$("#tooltip").mouseover(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}).mouseout(hide);
```

Where `#tip` is the element you want to mouseover to make the tooltip appear, and `#tooltip` is the actual tooltip element.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pvyhY/

---

If you wanted to wrap this in a jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.tooltip = function(tooltipEl) {
        var $tooltipEl = $(tooltipEl);
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);            
            var hide = function () {
                var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    $tooltipEl.hide();
                }, 500);

                $this.data("tooltip.timeout", timeout);
            };

            /* Bind an event handler to 'hover' (mouseover/mouseout): */
            $this.hover(function () {
                clearTimeout($this.data("tooltip.timeout"));
                $tooltipEl.show();
            }, hide);

            /* If the user is hovering over the tooltip div, cancel the timeout: */
            $tooltipEl.hover(function () {
                clearTimeout($this.data("tooltip.timeout"));
            }, hide);            
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tip").tooltip("#tooltip");
});
```

Add more functionality and you'll eventually end up with the excellent [qTip plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/EBsHK/), which I recommend taking a look at as well.

Comment: this is a good start to what I am looking for, I just need to delay showing anything on hover for a couple of seconds and if possible wrap it all into a class or function (im not sure that is the best idea with javascript but I think it will go with my other js better if it is in it's own shell so to speak), thanks for the code

Comment: @jason , if you have time use jquery hover intent very light weight plugin which is used for these type of stuff http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: @jasondavis: Good point; see updated code for a simple plugin implementation.