# Show tooltip onHover SlickGrid's row

Tags: jquery, .net, tooltip, title, slickgrid

Im newbie with jquery.

I've a task to put a tooltip on each row of a slickgrid.
I know how to ajax it. But, reading the slickgrid documentation there's nothing in options like "hover" or "tooltip".

my call is like that:

```
var grid = new gridd.Grid("#ite", result,
                [{ id: "var1", field: "var1" },
                    { id: "var2", field: "var2" },
                    { id: "var3", field: "var3", width: 100, resizable: false },
                    { id: "var4",  field: "var4", width: 110, resizable: false}],
                { forceFitColumns: true },
                //I thought of something like
                { onHover: function.. },
                //
                { onClick: function (e, row, cell) {
                    var result = this.getData();

                    postSomething(result[row]);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option that gets you the information is to subscribe to the grid's events `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`. The you can use whatever tooltip lib you want to have the text follow the mouse.

Use the event to discover which cell you are above. I use a dataview so need to use `view.getItem` in case any rows have been filtered out. If you are simply showing data without filtering, I believe `data[cell.row]` will work instead, but you'll need to test.

This will only get you the information to put in the tooltip, you'd need to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6638128) to get it in a tooltip following the mouse. For my test, I just updated a label (with id=`boringLabel`) and the label updated correctly.

```
var grid = new Slick.Grid(selector, view, cols, opts);

....

grid.onMouseLeave.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    $("#boringLabel").text("NONE");
});

grid.onMouseEnter.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    var cell = args.grid.getCellFromEvent(e);
    var item = view.getItem(cell.row);
    $("#boringLabel").text(item.id + " " + item.description);
});
```

Comment: well, first of all thank you @Edward for replying. I tried to subscribe the grid's events as u said, but firebug tells me that grid.onMouseLeave is undefined. And yes, i know how to make a cool div and put my data inside to popup.

Comment: Maybe because there's no onMouseLeave or onMouseEnter in the slickgrid js. Im using SlickGrid v1.4.3 - jquery-ui.slickgrid.js. Thank you agian.

Comment: @MalGaniS I'm on 2.0.1, that's probably why.

Comment: u were right budy, i just update the  slickgrid to 2.0 and boom! everything is working. Im calling another view as partialview and showing in the tooltip ! very cool ! thank you !

Comment: glad it helped you out @MalGaniS!