# Applying the CSS or changing format of label tooltip

Tags: asp.net

I have used a `Label` in a repeater control, which shows a tool tip. However, it is too small and is difficult to read. So I would like to change the format (apply css) to that tool tip.
Any ideas?

```
<td align="left" style="width: 145px">
     <asp:Label ID="lblItem" Text='<%# Eval("Add1").ToString().Substring(0, Math.Min(Eval("Add1").ToString().Length, 20))+"..." %>'
            ToolTip='<%# Eval("Add1")%>' runat="server" />
</td>
```

Comment: Find a similar type of answer which is using jquery to show the tooltip. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638128/jquery-tool-tip-on-hover

Comment: Thanks @TapasMahata I used it but it not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to show tool-tip, its best solution for this, see following link which can be help full to you.

[Animated Tooltip Javascript](http://ashishware.com/Tooltip.shtml) this will be very useful, and surely its working because I had already used them.