# I want to show tooltip on hover of a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a button with id #download_setup
Already one ajax is called in on click of this button.
but for some user i have to prevent this ajax download
Also i want to show a tooltip "you dont have permission to download"

using the below code, i displayed tooltip on onclick
But issue is that download is fired

```
$('#download_setup').on({
  "click": function(e) {
    $(this).tooltip({ items: "#download_setup", content: "Displaying on click"});
    $(this).tooltip("open");
     e.preventDefault();
  },
  "mouseout": function() {      
     $(this).tooltip("disable");   
  }
});
```

I added css to prevent on click
that time tooltip also wont work
i just want to display tooltip onclick or on mouse over, but not to fire ajax action
my css is below

```
#download_setup{
  pointer-events:none;opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery tool tip on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638128/jquery-tool-tip-on-hover)

Comment: Can you please show me the ajax call script without actual url, and how do you check the user? with js script? if so please also show us, then we can understand your code work flow. And ofcourse you should not use css `pointer-events:none` it will prevent all type of event works (click, hover, keyup, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It should must work

```
$("#download_setup").hover(function(){
        $(this).tooltip({ items: "#download_setup", content: "Displaying on click"});
        $(this).tooltip("open");
    }, function(){
         $(this).tooltip("disable"); 
});
```

Comment: Why you have pointer event none? tell me reason so I can give you alternate solution for that as well

Comment: is it working if you remove the css for pointer event? if yes then remove pointer event

Comment: yes, that already works in my above code also...   is there any way to prevent ajax action?

Comment: Yes, use a class to send ajax action after sending ajax you can remove that class from the tag by selecting the tag by its ID

Comment: Then you can use ajax only once